# Allow SSH Public Key Login to User on Server without Password

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

I'm running a few Docker Container at home for some personal training purpose (only local) to educate myself.

I want to SSH from one container to another container. Nearly everything is working. I have one issue with I cannot resolve / cannot understand at the moment.

In my docker container with the SSH Server I have only the root user. Root User has NO password. Therefore I have defined `PermitEmptyPasswords yes` in the sshd config file.

When I try to login from SSH Client to SSH Server (as root) I recieve the following error message: Persmission denied (publickey).

When I define a password for the root user the access is working fine, without issues.

Can somebody explain the issue I have in my configuration?

Thanks and kind regards
Holger